# Does this code look normal or should it be split into different modules?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I want to implement a module for interacting with user's multi-balances.
I have a service that works with the database through the repository
Please pay attention to decrease method

```
class UserBalanceModule {
  constructor(repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  } 

  isPositive(amount) {
    if (amount < 0) throw Error('The amount cannot be less than 0');
    return true;
  }

  isAllowed(code, userId, amount) {
    this.isPositive(amount);
    const balance = this.findByCodeAndUserId(code, userId);
    const status = balance - amount >= 0;

    if (!status) throw Error('Insufficient funds');

    return true;
  }

  create(userId) {
    if (!userId) throw Error('userId empty');

    const item = this.repo.create(userId);
    return item;
  }

  findByCodeAndUserId(code, userId) {
    if (!code || !userId) throw Error('incorrect parameters');

    const result = this.repo.findByCodeAndUserId(code, userId);
    return result;
  }

  decrease(code, userId, amount) {
     this.isAllowed(code, userId, amount);

    const result = this.repo.decrease(code, userId, amount);
    return result;
  }
}
```

I am concerned about the 2 methods isPositive and isAllowed, in fact they only work with numbers and have nothing to do with the operation of the database. Do you think it would be logical to leave the code as it is now or put it in a separate module?

```
class BalanceModule {
   constructor(balance = 0, amount) {
     this.balance = balance;
     this.amount = amount;
   }

    isPositive() {
        if (this.amount < 0) throw Error('The amount cannot be less than 0');
        return true;
    }

    isAllowed() {
        this.isPositive();
        const status = this.balance - this.amount >= 0;

        if (!status) throw Error('Insufficient funds');

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO its absolute fine to keep this two methods. But what you definitely should change is the error throw in "isPositive". The name of the method suggests, that it either returns true or false and doesn't throw an error. An external caller could easily misinterpret this and therefore omits the try/catch around it when calling it. Same for isAllowed (methods starting with "is" shouldn't throw an error when the result would be false, as this is an expected possible outcome).

Comment: When in doubt, don't separate the code out into another file/location (at least imo). You want related bits of code to be close together so it'll be easier to read/understand the code later without having to jump around between files.

Comment: Also, as MBPictures pointed out, names like `isAllowed()` makes it sound like it returns a boolean. I'd suggest something like `ensureAllowed()`.